# Unity3D & Android: Difference between "UnityMain" and "main" threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, unity-game-engine

**TLDR:** I'm using JNI to call into my custom JAR from Unity C#. But the android library says it's running on the "UnityMain" thread, while the actual ui thread for the activity is called "main". What is the difference between the two?

**Details:**
This is a problem for me since I get the error "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". Here's the output I get when printing the two threads from Java:

```
/// Java Output
Current Thread:    Thread[UnityMain,5,main]
MainLooper Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
```

To resolve this, I'm running the JNI calls using the Activity.runOnUiThread method:

```
/// Unity C# Code
activityObj.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() => {
  // JNI calls and other stuff
}
```

Now I get the following output when printing the two threads from Java:

```
/// Java Output
Current Thread:    Thread[main,5,main]
MainLooper Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
```

Only problem now is that I can't make Unity Coroutine or Invoke calls from the "main" thread (i.e. inside the "runOnUiThread" callback). I get the following Unity error:

```
/// Unity C# Output
E/Unity   (21048): Invoke can only be called from the main thread.
E/Unity   (21048): Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
E/Unity   (21048): Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
```

So what is the difference between the "UnityMain" and "main" threads? And why is the Java "main" thread different from that of Unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity runs its own thread to handle its processing. It doesn't usurp the Android main thread created by the Android OS when launching the app. Typically when you write a traditional Android app there is only one main thread, and everything that deals with the UI must run on the main thread. To use a second "main" thread, was a design choice made by Unity, probably so it can do whatever it wants without messing with the apps Android main thread. If you want to do anything in the Android UI outside of Unity you'll need to have your code run on the main thread. You can do this from anywhere using the below snippet:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("MAIN", "Thread? " + Thread.currentThread());
    }
});
```

If the Android/Java code you are calling into has access to the Application context or an Activity context you can use `runOnUiThread` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I hadn't been able to use the "new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())" approach since the handler initialization was inside a library that my library was using. Just found the source for the library, modified it, and everything works as expected now.

Comment: modifying blackbox libraries is a bad idea