# Can't start a Handler on the main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a .jar api to read Google Fit data from Unity3D. The problem that I'm facing right now is that when I want to execute this block of code:

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(myContext).addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new ConnectionCallbacksListener())
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, new ConnectionFailedListener()).build();
}
```

I get the error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from main thread of process

This error is due to the **this** reference in the last sentence of the line of code.

Now online I found that I could fix this by starting a Handler on the Main Looper, I tried this with this code:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        buildFitnessClient();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.i(TAG, ex.getMessage() + "\n");
                    }
                }
            });
```

For some reason my Unity app instantly crashes, usually I can get the error since I use a try catch statement. With this problem it instantly crashes and there is no log I can check.

When I create my Handler without the mainlooper, like:

```
new Handler()
```

or

```
new Handler(Looper.myLooper())
```

The code runs, but the java.lang.IllegalStateException error remains, and the Thread.currentThread() obviously remains the same.

The thread that the program runs on is a thread created by Unity.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like the same problem I'm having but it doesn't fix anything for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953890/unity3d-android-difference-between-unitymain-and-main-threads?rq=1

Comment: It seems like the thread starter works, it crashes on the method that builds the fitness client?

Comment: the program crashes on 'this' in the enableAutoManage(this, 0, ....